# Fieldset and legend tag does't work in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I've used a master page (.cshtml page) and a sub page (.cshtml page) under that master page. When I use `<fieldset></fieldset>` & `<legend></legend>` tag inside sub page it shows a horizontal line instead of actual output of `<fieldset></fieldset>` & `<legend></legend>` tag. How can I solve it?

[This is my master page](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14532285/)

[This is my sub page](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14532760/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Views>Shared>_Layout.cshtml.
then comment -->  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") .
then it will work